# C# how do i subtract from a value inside a textbox?

Tags: c#

this is what i currently have at the moment. when i enter a value into the uiBasket1000TextBox i want it to subtract that value off of the uiStock1000TextBox. how would i perform such a task?

```
this.uiBasket1000TextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(75, 55); 
this.uiBasket1000TextBox.Name = "uiBasket1000TextBox"; 
this.uiBasket1000TextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20); 
this.uiBasket1000TextBox.TabIndex = 1; 
this.uiBasket1000TextBox.Text = "0"

this.uiStock1000TextBox.Enabled = false; 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 55); 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.Name = "uiStock1000TextBox"; 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 20); 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.TabIndex = 11; 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.TabStop = false; 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.Text = "3238"; 
this.uiStock1000TextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.uiStock1000Text..
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  First of all, subtraction is a mathematical term.  Are you talking about numbers here?  Or do you mean you want to return a substring somehow (i.e. nothing to do with subtraction)?

Comment: The simplest solution would to be create a method to perform your task, then assign it as `uiStock1000TextBox.TextChanged`'s event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide more details about what you have in those textboxes, but the following should get you started:

```
 Decimal stockValue = Convert.ToDecimal(uiStock1000TextBox.Text);
 Decimal basketValue = Convert.ToDecimal(uiBasket1000TextBox.Text);
 uiStock1000TextBox.Text = (stockValue - basketValue).ToString();
```

Of course, you should consider value that cannot be converted by using [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) function. Also, I would also take a look upon [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx), as it is highly recommended to work with data, not parse text.

Answer (score 1):

You get the value, parse it to an Int/Double/Decimal, perform the subtraction and then set it back as the textbox text.

```
var value = int.Parse(uiStock1000Textbox.Text);
uiStock1000Textbox.Text = (value - 10).ToString();
```

Comment: You may want to try a `TryParse` instead as you have no clue what the user is going to enter.

Comment: @DavidPilkington that was just an example, not production code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Convert rather than Parse.

```
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(uiStock1000Textbox.Text);
int difference = num1 - 100;
```